# Passing value from view to controller by clicking an attribute

Tags: view, asp.net-core, controller

I am trying to pass these values back to my controller for some basic paging and I am not sure why it is not getting them.

Am I using asp-route incorrectly to pass them?

View:

```
<ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous"><a asp-action="Index" asp-route-prev="@Model.First().ID">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a asp-action="Index" asp-route-next="@Model.Last().ID">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexPost(string certification, string category, string resource, int prev, int next)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a asp-action="Index" asp-route-prev="@Model.First().ID">Previous</a>
```

Above code renders ***a*** tag which makes ***HttpGet*** request to action method, if you click on it.

If you want to make ***HttpPost***, you will need to use ***form*** tag, and ***button*** or ***input*** tag with type submit.

```
<ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous">
       <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" 
             asp-route-prev="@Model.First().ID" method="post" role="form">
           <button type="submit">Previous</button>
       </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Another way is to post the form using JavaScript or jQuery on a click, but it is a bit out of the scope of original question.